# How to send Chatbase Intents in BLiP

Tags: chatbase

I have a chatbot made with BLiP's Builder.
I'm trying to integrate Chatbase with it but I was unable to set the intent of my user's inputs.

I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this beside the generic API, but I've seen people in the BLiP forums saying they have that setup.

There is an option to send a full http request and that should work, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using the tools' native integration.

Comment: Here you have all the info you need to set the parameters to not handled at Blip! https://help.blip.ai/docs/en/analytics/chatbase/tratando-eventos-not-handled-sessionFlow-chatbase/#docsNav It took some time for me to find it, but I did and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question. Chatbase does not have a native integration with Blip, therefore you would need to use the generic API in order to fully integrate your bot.